# vsftpd not listing large directory from WAN interface

Tags: networking, ftp

I have vsftpd running on my Ubuntu server, which is behind an Asus RT-N66U router. Port 21 is forwarded to the server.

I can connect via my public IP address to the server, and it lists the files in the home directory. If I then attempt to change directory to one containing many files, it simply hangs with "150 Here comes the directory listing", and after a few seconds gives me an error (421 Timeout) and closes the connection.

When connecting via the server's local IP within the LAN, the behaviour is normal (and much more responsive), and I have no trouble listing directories with thousands of files.

What could the matter be?